# SSIS package not inserting records when run as Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Hi I want to run my SSIS package as job. I have successfully created job and package. It runs without any error but it is not inserting records to the database.

[image]

But when I run the same package using DTEXECUI.EXE It is inserting records in the database. Please help.

Comment: It may be missing autorizations? Any messages in eventlog? Have you tried running profiler / Ext. Events?

Comment: In history there is message The job succeed

Comment: The same job is running successfully in my local system.

Comment: Does the SQL agent user have access to your packages? As @NickyvV has already mentioned check the Event Logs/SQL Server profiler to see if you can get anymore information.

Comment: Thanks but I am very new to sssis I am not aware of these steps... more explanation is highly appreciated...

Comment: In SSMS, if you go to Tools > SQL Server Profiler > Click Connect > Run. Then go back to the SQL Agent Job and Start it, you should see the profiler then add events relating to the running job. Once the Job has finished click Pause on the profiler and then have a look at the events to see if there is anything that stands out.

Comment: Could it be that the connection is going to another system and that is the one that is getting updated? I cannot see the trace file, however I would air on the side of caution posting it as it might contain sensitive information.

Comment: So Please advice what to do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47660/discussion-between-peter-r-and-maxpayne)

Comment: Yes you are right Peter_R ... the records are updating on the other table ... (The original one) but I am not aware how connection string is changing at run time I have set environment variable to test table.

Comment: Please continue this in the chat window listed above to keep the comments section clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, it was discovered that the package was using `Environment Variables` as part of the connection manager, SQL Server/Agent/SSIS service needed to be restarted for these new variables to be picked up.